# Alexa Skill - Dynamic Invocation Name

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa Skill.

Right now I have hard coded my invocation name in my amazon console. I have a ruby admin panel which handles all other activities happening inside.

Is there any way I can put the Invocation Name via an admin panel and pass it on to Alexa skill like an API, which could change my skill's invocation name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Innovation name cannot be changed via an API. You can change your invocation name at any time while developing a skill. You cannot change the invocation name after a skill is certified and published.

**ASK-CLI**
However, you can use `ASK-CLI` to deploy/update a skill and you can also change your invocation name in the corresponding interaction model.

More on ASK CLI [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html)